# how to extract string inside single quotes using python script

Tags: python, regex, strip, findall, recompile

Have a set of string as follows

```
text:u'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-25'
text:u'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-26'
text:u'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-27'
```

These data i have extracted from a Xls file and converted to `string`,
now i have to Extract data which is inside single quotes and put them in a list.

expecting output like

```
[MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-25, MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-26,MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-27]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = """text:u'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-25'
text:u'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-26'
text:u'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-27'"""
>>> re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", strs, re.DOTALL)
['MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-25',
 'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-26',
 'MUC-EC-099_SC-Memory-01_TC-27'
]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following expression:

```
(?<=')[^']+(?=')
```

This matches zero or more characters that are not `'` which are enclosed between `'` and `'`.

Python Code:

```
quoted = re.compile("(?<=')[^']+(?=')")
for value in quoted.findall(str(row[1])):
    i.append(value)
    print i
```

Comment: @Mr.Calm You are welcome, I will add your code to the answer. Please don't forget to accept the answer when you can. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

That `text:` prefix seems a little familiar.  Are you using `xlrd` to extract it?  In that case, the reason you have the prefix is because you're getting the wrapped `Cell` object, not the value in the cell.  For example, I think you're doing something like

```
>>> sheet.cell(2,2)
number:4.0
>>> sheet.cell(3,3)
text:u'C'
```

To get the unwrapped object, use `.value`:

```
>>> sheet.cell(3,3).value
u'C'
```

(Remember that the `u` here is simply telling you the string is unicode; it's not a problem.)